# optional chaining operator in node modules not working in linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, node-modules

[this is the error i am facing when i try to run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK51z.png)

`const contentType = response?.headers['content-type'];`

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object. (/home/pranav/mona/monacip-backend/node_modules/@api.video/nodejs-client/lib/index.js:15:38)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)

this `?.` operator is not working on ubuntu machines

Comment: Which node version is installed?

Comment: 10.19.0 @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Is there a reason to use such an old version? Only Node.js 14 and upwards supports that operator

Comment: i dont know why ubuntu installed such old version, i never specified the version

Comment: i will just update the node once then will try again

Comment: Then I suggest installing a newer one and the problem disappears

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i tried updating node but it is not updating, still it is showing 10.19.0 only

Comment: Did you read the instructions on Node.js website? They’re the ones providing the software, not Ubuntu